# Die Ordnungszahl 63 wurde in der DLL "libexpat.dll" nicht gefunden

Tags: python, python-2.5, qgis

I have a Python 2.5 program with code at

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh1sgpsd248x85m/PopGen.zip

When I execute this program (python -m gui.mainwindow), I get the error message "Die Ordnungszahl 63 wurde in der DLL "libexpat.dll" nicht gefunden." (sorry, I don't know how to translate "Ordnungszahl" to English, literal translation - "ordering number").

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1osw18xlz8tcjt8/2.png]

When I look at the output of the program, I see the error

Error occurred importing qgis; no mapping support will be provided. Error message- DLL load failed with error code 182

[image]

This program makes use of the Quantum GIS (qgis) package, which is installed and the path with the DLL is included.

One possible cause of the problem is that there is another, older version of libexpat.dll in system32. But this isn't the case on my machine.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The message translates as "Ordinal Not Found" and means that you're linking to the wrong version of the DLL.

Comment: Cool. A guy with a russian name asks a question in english about a message in german.

Comment: maybe someone should answer in spanish then... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. Installing a different version of QGIS solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like the issue is an incompatible/ old version of libexpat.dll](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors#Error_message_.22The_ordinal_63_could_not_be_located_in_the_dynamic_link_libexpat.dll..22) or in my case, no copy of it at all. I cheated and downloaded a copy of the DLL to the relevant Windows system folder.